# How to return the records and apply specific condition in SQL column

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, substring

I have a table called A , in which there are multiple columns , one columns consist of json in which I am inserting settings.

for example that column contains .

```
{"ID":"79","NameEn":"Medical - Gross Premiums by Company (TTM) (%)","NameAr":"الحصة من أقساط القطاع الصحي (%) (آخر 12 شهراً)","Key":"insurance-ranking","apiEndPoint":"tools-ranking","uidMapping":"6","sn":"0","ac":"0","arg":"companyids,tcid,language,tcvalue,companyid","UID":"6-15-79-44-T","fiscalPeriods":{"periods":"[]","IsSelected":""},"fiscalYEars":{"years":"[]","fullViewYears":"[]","IsSelected":""},"tbc":"[1,2,3]"}
```

As seen above it contains different keys and its values , I want to return the records but  I want to apply specific condition that is in NameEn and NameAr , I just want to return the part that contains brackets , and exlude the remaining part.

For Example : My desired result of above row is

```
{"ID":"79","NameEn":"(TTM) (%)","NameAr":" (%) (آخر 12 شهراً)","Key":"insurance-ranking","apiEndPoint":"tools-ranking","uidMapping":"6","sn":"0","ac":"0","arg":"companyids,tcid,language,tcvalue,companyid","UID":"6-15-79-44-T","fiscalPeriods":{"periods":"[]","IsSelected":""},"fiscalYEars":{"years":"[]","fullViewYears":"[]","IsSelected":""},"tbc":"[1,2,3]"}
```

Comment: This is only a description f what you want. Which specific problem do you face while implementing it?

Answer (score -1):

I have used the following logic I pick the first bracket and get all the substring from there

```
 SUBSTRING(JSON_VALUE(Parameters,'$.NameEn') ,CHARINDEX('(',JSON_VALUE(Parameters,'$.NameEn'))+0,LEN(JSON_VALUE(Parameters,'$.NameEn'))) UnitsEn
```

Comment: Edit your Question to include this additional information. This site isn't a traditional "message board", rather a Q&A site.